# sysmbols for the module test.dll were not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

In my solution i have 6 class libraries and the application is executed successfully but when i tried to debug one class i am getting the message for one of my dll "sysmbols for the module test.dll were not loaded".see the below image

[image]

so, this popup box got stopped me to debug my application. can anyone pls help me to fix this ?